# Mirroring Without Changing Faces

Tags: texturing, normals, mirror

I need to mirror a mesh (square building window) to fit the right side of the building face.

When I mirror it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> it changes the normal and it looks weird on texturing.

Is there any way to change the normal individually for each mesh?
It's a 4 side building hence 4 normals for each side of the building and while doing this.

While writing it I figured out that the color space in the *Image Texture* (of normal) node is set to *sRGB* instead of *Linear*.

Comment: Try to flip the normals F3 search recalculate Normals